# Multiply by number of days in a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've had a decent search on here but can't seem to find what I'm looking for, I think I'm using an incorrect syntax for GETDATE

I'm trying to use a formula that we use as a company to work within my code.  That is;

```
The Price of something / Days in year * days in the month
```

I'm trying to use the following but to no avail -

```
[Rate] =  Price/'365'*month([Period])))
```

'Period' is the column name which has the date of the month in the format '2018-04-01' for example
This is based on an example a colleague has shown me but I can't get it to work as I think I'm writing it totally wrong

Apologies for the simple question, I'm brand new to SQL code (well only started in April) so some simple things till are oblivious to me!

Any help here would be really appreciated

Cheers

W

Comment: Your parentheses don't balance.

Comment: [Rate] =  Price/('365'*month(Period))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code will be like below

```
[Rate] =  (Price*1.00/365) * datepart(day, period)
```

below is an example by using getdate()

```
select rate= (12*1.00/365) * datepart(day, getdate())
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this (assuming 365 days in a year):

```
select (price / 365.0) * day(eomonth(period)) as rate
```

If you want to take leap years into account, then:

```
select (case when eomonth(day(year(period)), 2, 1)) = 28
             then (price / 365.0) * day(eomonth(period))
             else (price / 366.0) * day(eomonth(period))
        end) as rate
```

Comment: Thanks for that - tried to use the leap year option as this will be what I need, however it returned the following error; Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The day function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: Shouldn't the second `then` be `else`?